# AWS: connection refused error for the reactjs app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2

I setup project on the aws ec2. I am able to build the project but not able to access it. Here is the error from log
[error] 14462#14462: *23 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.243.37.87, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://xxx.31.45.195:3000/favicon.ico", host: "13.xxx.109.248", referrer: "http://13.xxx.109.248/"

```
server {
 listen 80;
 root /var/www/react-web/build;
 location / {
 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
 proxy_http_version 1.1;
 proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
 proxy_set_header Connection ‘upgrade’;
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
 }
}
```

Can anybody help me to fix the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Connection refused usually means there is no app listening on the specified port. In this case 80.

Comment: @RomiHalasz please check i have updated the description.